# Swift - how do I allow the textfield to still recognize spaces after the correct answer inputed as still the correct answer

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am making a quiz where there is a textfield and the user enters an answer. However, I want it to recognize that a space after the correct answer is still correct. For example if the answer is Red and the user enters Red  with a space after Red, it is still recognized as the correct answer. Below is my code. Please let me know and thanks for all your help in advance!

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

class Case1Q3ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var questionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var correctAnswerLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var inputTextField: UITextField!

    var enteredAnswer: String?

    var correctAnswer = "Well demarcated"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(InputViewController1.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(InputViewController1.keyboardWillHide), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

        inputTextField.delegate = self

        titlesForLabels()
        nextButton.enabled = false
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func titlesForLabels() {
        questionLabel.text = "Describe the borders"
        correctAnswerLabel.text = correctAnswer
        correctAnswerLabel.hidden = true

        inputTextField.text = nil
        inputTextField.enabled = true
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

        let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardFrame.size.height
        })
    }

    func keyboardWillHide() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
        })
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        enteredAnswer = textField.text

        checkForCorrectAnswer()

        return true
    }

    func checkForCorrectAnswer() {
        if enteredAnswer!.lowercaseString == correctAnswer.lowercaseString {
            print("Correct")
            correctAnswerLabel.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            correctAnswerLabel.text = "Correct!"
            nextButton.enabled = true

        } else {
            print("Wrong Answer")
            correctAnswerLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
            correctAnswerLabel.text = "Incorrect! Please try again"
            nextButton.enabled = false

        }
        correctAnswerLabel.hidden = false
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        navigationItem.title = "Case 1 - Q3"
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alex how is this a duplicate of my other question? My other question was asking about how do I make the next question button appear only after the correct answer is chosen. 

This question is asking how can I make the textfield portion of a quiz recognize the answer even if a space is added at the end of it

These are not the same question

Comment: cannot remember now what the intention behind the link was but it was wrong as it was pointing to this exact question. I have removed my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should trim the whitespace before checking the equality. You can use the [stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:) method for this purpose.

```
func checkForCorrectAnswer()
{
    let answer = enteredAnswer!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
    if answer.lowercaseString == correctAnswer.lowercaseString
    {
        print("Correct")
        correctAnswerLabel.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        correctAnswerLabel.text = "Correct!"
        nextButton.enabled = true

    }
    else
    {
        print("Wrong Answer")
        correctAnswerLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        correctAnswerLabel.text = "Incorrect! Please try again"
        nextButton.enabled = false

    }
    correctAnswerLabel.hidden = false
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked beautifully!

Comment: @Babz if this solved your problem then you should click the check mark to accept the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like this:

```
let str = "Hi How Are You"
let newString = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
print(newString) //This prints "HiHowAreYou"
```

Then just compare the users answer to the correct answer both without spaces. In your case you would use something like this:

```
if enteredAnswer.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "").lowercaseString == correctAnswer.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "").lowercaseString {
//Answer Is Correct
```

}

Comment: I am a little new to coding and swift. I am not following sorry. So in my code provided, the correct answer to the question is "plaque". How would I make it recognize that "plaque " is also correct (i.e. there is a space after plaque). If you could edit my code to show me this, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Q: "What is the right spellig: 'file name' or 'filename'?" How could one give the wrong answer?